# Whisper AI throws the error: std::runtime_error

Tags: 22.04, python

Initially I was able to run Whisper on my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and it worked well. After some:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I faced with the following:

```
~: whisper --version
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  expected ident but found 'eof' here:

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Whisper file in 'bin' folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from whisper.transcribe import cli
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(cli())
```

Any ideas how to investigate/resolve the issue?
I am desperately trying to switch from windows to Ubuntu and already fed up with re-installation of the OS due to different issues appearing after updates.
Thanks

Comment: Well. The issue was in PyTorch library. I don't know exactly how I fixed that, just uninstall ed CUDA and PyTorch and installed PyTorch again.

Answer (score 0):

Well. The issue was in PyTorch library. I don't know exactly how I fixed it, just try to uninstall CUDA and PyTorch and to install PyTorch again.